# How can I get rid of permission denied error when executing man to read the manpages?

Tags: command-line, zsh, man

I'm getting a permission denied error when trying to access the manpages of all executables.  For example, here's the following command:

`% man cat`

Here's one of the errors returned:

> zsh: permission denied: man

The following is another error returned:

> env: ‘man’: Permission denied

I haven't been able to find out the root cause of these errors.

Here are the outputs requested:

`% type man`

> man is a shell function from /home/procer/.xdg/config/antigen/bundles/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/plugins/colored-man-pages/colored-man-pages.plugin.zsh

`% ls -l $(command -v man)`

> ls: cannot access 'man': No such file or directory

Comment: You appear to have installed some plugin, which does not work. Try running `/usr/bin/man`.

Comment: I tried running /usr/bin/man and it returned: `zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/bin/man`.  Then I tried installing man with pacman, then it installed it at /usr/bin but now it returns `No manual entry for man` when I run `% man man`.  Any ideas?